# What does it mean for a firm to have a 0.95% dividend?

Tags: finance, stock-market

Here's an Apple's dividend: [image]

What does this 0.95% mean? Is it 0.95% of share capital? If not, what does it mean?

Comment: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/dividendpayoutratio.asp

Answer (score 3):

As of the market close on 2/14/2020, Apple's stock price was \$324.95 per share. The forward looking dividend (based on announced dividend policy over the next year) is \$3.08 per share. The [forward looking dividend yield](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/forward-dividend-yield.asp) is therefore $\frac{3.08}{324.95} = 0.00948$ or 0.95%. This means that for every share, the firm is planning to pay out \$3.08 over the next year, so the effective yield is that payout over the current stock price. Essentially, every \$100 invested in Apple will throw off 95 cents of cash over the next year.

[image]
Source: [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL&.tsrc=fin-srch)